# Specific Values in Json Parse

Tags: ruby, json, parsing

I am having difficulty getting to specific values when I parse a JSON file in Ruby.  My JSON is based off of this link https://www.mcdonalds.com/services/mcd/us/restaurantLocator?latitude=40.7217861&longitude=-74.00944709999999&radius=8045&maxResults=100&country=us&language=en-us

No matter what I try I cannot pull the values I want, which is the "addressLine1" field.  I get the following error:

```
`[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
```

Code

```
require 'json'

file = File.read('MCD.json')
data_hash = JSON.parse(file)


print data_hash.keys
print "\n"

print data_hash['features']['addressLine1']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data_hash['features']` is an array. Depending on what do you actually need, you might either iterate over it, or call:

```
data_hash['features'].first['properties']['addressLine1']
```

Note `'properties'` there, since `addressLine1` is not a direct descendant of `'features'` elements.

Comment: This is helpful.  Now just need to iterate to get the entire file.